# How to show another graph when a data point or bar is clicked

Tags: jqplot

I have a question: 
**Is it possible to draw another graph when a data point or a bar in bar chart is clicked?**

For example, in a line graph there are 5 points drawn and when a point is clicked the inner data for that point is drawn in another chart. Suppose the point is the total bread sold for the month, and when this point is clicked another graph should be drawn showing total bread sold for each week.

Thanks in advance!..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try redrawing the graph with the new inputs. Which programming language, chart product are you using?

Comment: THanks for the soon reply,I'm using GWT to give data to charts.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it very easily with `jqPlot`.
[Please check out this live sample on jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Boro/2ucjy/)

When you are there just click on the dots of the 1st visible graph and the second will be always painted for the clicked data.

Comment: Thanks Boro, This is what I have been looking for. Thant function with ev,seriesIndex..and so on is the solution for me!..

Comment: @ShamithaSilva Great to here it helped.